# SQL Select multiple values in one column, with different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I've products-filter relation table.

For example: I want to select all products with color red and yellow which have medium size

```
WHERE (filter_id = 208 OR filter_id = 211) AND filter_id = 210
```

I'cant figure out how to use AND condition on same column

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to group your data by `product_id` and the take only those having the conditions you mentioned

```
select product_id
from your_table
group by product_id
having sum(filter_id = 210) > 0
   and sum(filter_id = 208 OR filter_id = 211) > 0
```